# Query too slow in Postgresql in table with > 12M rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table with more than 12 Million rows growing every time, in my web app.

```
+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
| id  | dtt | cus  | event | server |
-------------------------------------
```

I'm getting the count of today events by customer using this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM events
    WHERE dtt AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago' >=date(now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago') + interval '1s' 
    AND cus=2
```

And the performance is very bad for my web app : 22702 ms.

```
"Aggregate  (cost=685814.54..685814.55 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=21773.451..21773.452 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..675644.52 rows=4068008 width=0) (actual time=10277.508..21732.548 rows=409808 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((cus = 2) AND (timezone('America/Santiago'::text, dtt) >= (date(timezone('America/Santiago'::text, now())) + '00:00:01'::interval)))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 12077798"
"Planning time: 0.127 ms"
"Execution time: 21773.509 ms"
```

I have the next Indexes created:

```
CREATE INDEX events_dtt_idx
  ON events
  USING btree
  (dtt);

CREATE INDEX events_id_desc
  ON events
  USING btree
  (id DESC NULLS LAST);

CREATE INDEX events_cus_idx
  ON events
  USING btree
  (cus);

CREATE INDEX events_id_idx
  ON events
  USING btree
  (id);
```

Using Postgresql 9.4,  Linux x64
How can I improve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you'll create index on `dtt AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'` ?

Comment: functional index should to work - the only one risk is slightly over estimation.

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
CREATE INDEX dtt_tz_idx ON  events (DATE(dtt AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'));
```

then query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM events
    WHERE DATE(TIMEZONE('America/Santiago'::text, dtt)) >=date(now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago') + interval '1s' 
    AND cus=2
```

If it doesn't work, try "\d dtt_tz_idx" in psql and try to match the datatypes on your query with the index.

Comment: That query is getting 0 matches, something is wrong with the query, the original query gets 537596 matches.

Comment: The problem is the first DATE() function, if I remove the first DATE function, the performance is the same, nothing improved.

Comment: did you check if the datataypes of your index and your query match?

Comment: yes, but the problem in your answer is other, the query, then the index doesn't work, I could get a solution and just post an answer, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could fix the problem with that index:

```
CREATE INDEX dtt_tz_idx ON  events (TIMEZONE('America/Santiago'::text, dtt));
```

Thanks sivan & vyegorov for your guide, now the plan is:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=567240.43..567240.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=238.440..238.440 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=82620.28..556463.97 rows=4310584 width=0) (actual time=41.445..208.870 rows=344453 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (timezone('America/Santiago'::text, dtt) >= (date(timezone('America/Santiago'::text, now())) + '00:00:01'::interval))"
"        Filter: (cus = 2)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 9433"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=9426"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dtt_tz_idx  (cost=0.00..81542.63 rows=4415225 width=0) (actual time=38.866..38.866 rows=353886 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (timezone('America/Santiago'::text, dtt) >= (date(timezone('America/Santiago'::text, now())) + '00:00:01'::interval))"
"Planning time: 0.221 ms"
"Execution time: 238.509 ms"
```